# Is there a Catch2 variable that provides the name of the current test?

Tags: c++, catch2

I'm using [Catch2](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2) for unit tests and I would like to know the name of a C++ or environment variable that reveals the name of the current test that is executing.

Is there a way to do this, or is it bad form to have the test debugging code print the name of the test in which it is running? Ideally I'd like to print it using the [CAPTURE](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/2c269eb6332bc1dd29047851ae1efc3cd4c260d2/docs/logging.md) Macro.

The reason that I want to do this is that I have many Catch2 tests and some of them generate voluminous output. Some generate the exact same output. Some generate output that *should* be the same but sometimes isn't. The output is not generated in the body of the unit test, but instead in a function called. So I would like to be able to label the output according to the macro that generated it.

I suppose that one way to do this would be to use a scaffold that stores the name into a global variable, or an environment variable.

Comment: I doubt there would be an ENV variable for that, given that the tests all execute within the same process. What exactly do you need the name of the test for anyway? You mention the `CAPTURE` macro, but usually the test output is seen per-test already -- and so usually it's quite clear which output is associated to which test.

Comment: You can create and remove environment variables with `getenv()` and `putenv()`. I do it all the time. it's another global variable scope. It's really cool....

Comment: As far as the `CAPTURE` macro ...  I have extensive logging from some of my tests to files, and there are common functions that are called by multiple tests. Yes, it would be nicer to have low-level unit tests, and I do, but there are some higher-level ones that need testing too...

Comment: I wonder WHY? What are you trying to achieve? Maybe there is better alternative solutions? Test name is printed on case of test failure by `Catch2`.

Comment: Offtopic `environment variable` is something setup by system or process which start current process, `Catch2` doesn't any reason to change `environment variable`.

Comment: I have updated the question to answer @MarekR's question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your scaffolding idea is the way to go. I have not found any macros that would return the name without having to define an extra variable.

When it comes to the class that is being instantiated for a test case:

```cpp
struct AutoReg : Detail::NonCopyable {
    AutoReg( Detail::unique_ptr<ITestInvoker> invoker, SourceLineInfo const& lineInfo, StringRef classOrMethod, NameAndTags const& nameAndTags ) noexcept;
};
```

It doesn't have any members that would hold test info and even if it did you'd have to keep track of the unique name it's given for each test.

Looks like `AutoReg` simply modifies members of a class called `RegistryHub`, which holds the test info in vectors.

In my opinion at this point you're better off keeping track of test names yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There is a depreciated API (v2.13)

```
Catch::getResultCapture().getCurrentTestName()
```

that does exactly this.  But before you get too excited, the comment in the header for `getCurrentTestName()` literally says "Deprecated, do not use".

Regardless I use it and find it very helpful in my particular use case.